# Почему select выводит по несколько раз?

Tags: mysql

Модель моей бд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И запрос + результат (можете пожалуйста объяснить почему так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каков запрос, таков и ответ

Comment: Может скажете что не так?

Comment: Что по вашему значит `FROM table1, table2, table3` ?

Comment: выбираем из каких таблиц?

Comment: Ну вот он вам комбинации и собрал из этих таблиц. Для правильной выборки вы должны указывать как и через что каждую из таблиц соединять.

Comment: с помощью where?

Comment: С помощью `JOIN ON`. `WHERE` хотя и можно использовать для этого, но его лучше использовать для фильтрации данных

Comment: Почитайте учебники по SQL, в частности разделы про JOIN

Comment: спасибо я знаю про джойны просто не дагодался

Comment: я сделал если кому интересно, сам ответил на свой  вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сделал,

```
SELECT Rating,FirstName,SecondName,Name from Employees inner join AssessmentRating
on AssessmentRating.Employees_idEmployees = Employees.idEmployees
inner join Location 
on Location.Company_idCompany = Employees.Company_idCompany;
```